# nginx: error_page doesn't work with rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have this nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name tds.my;
    root /home/tds;
    index index.php;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /errs/50x.html;
    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 /errs/404.html;

    if ( $request_uri !~ "/errs|index\.php" ) {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fcgi.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

index.php generates an error with status 500.
The link http://tds.my/index.php returns the static page http://tds.my/errs/50x.html, but the link http://tds.my/example.php doesn't return a static page. I think it happens because rewrite is used.

How can I configure nginx to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the directive [recursive_error_pages](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#recursive_error_pages), and it works for me. And kudos to [Jim D](https://serverfault.com/a/252721/179393).